# WeakReference in inner static class is null(cleared) to outer class

Tags: java, static, inner-classes, weak-references

I am new to java.
I can not understand what I do wrong. I set a weak reference in static inner class to the outer class. Debug showed me that weak reference is set correct. But when call callback ( LocationGps locatGps=locationGps1.get();) the weak reference is null.

```java
public class LocationGps implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

    private LocationChangeListeningActivityLocationCallback callback =
            new LocationChangeListeningActivityLocationCallback(this);

    private static class LocationChangeListeningActivityLocationCallback
            implements LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {
        private final WeakReference<LocationGps> locationGps1;

        LocationChangeListeningActivityLocationCallback(LocationGps locationGps){
            locationGps1 = new WeakReference<LocationGps>(locationGps);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
            Log.wtf("WHS locationGPS", String.valueOf(result.getLocations()));
            LocationGps locatGps = locationGps1.get();
            locatGps.collbackSetLocation(result.getLastLocation());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is that necessarily surprising?  Do you have another reference to the `LocationGps` somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

> But when call callback ( `LocationGps locatGps=locationGps1.get();` ) the `WeakReference` is `null`.

Your code just needs to deal with this.

The point of a `WeakReference` is that is *can* be broken if the garbage collector determines that there are no stronger references to the object<sup>1</sup>.  So if you use a `WeakReference` your code needs to cope with the possibility of the ref being broken.  Or ... conversely ... if your code cannot cope then you should use an ordinary (strong) reference which the GC *won't* break.

If you used `SoftReference` rather than `WeakReference`, the GC would only break the link if it was running short of heap space.  That *may* reduce the likelihood that the reference was broken.

---

On the other hand, if the inner class *wasn't* declared as `static`, it would have an implicit link to an instance of the enclosing type, and you could replace

```
LocationGps locatGps = locationGps1.get();
```

with

```
LocationGps locatGps = LocationGps.this;
```

Note that `LocationGps.this` is a strong reference to an instance of the outer class.

---

<sup>1 - Since you have see the ref breaking, it follows that the GC *has* detected that there are not stronger references, and has decided to break the link.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for answer. I use example https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/. Activity use static class as callback of GPS update location variable to avoid memory leak. I make the same, but Activity use additional class to split code readability. But this approach does not work.  Can i struck of memory leak Without weakrefference?

Comment: @Stas: your code works very differently to the sample code you link to. The sample code holds a weak reference to the **main activity**. The activity is a long-ish lived object that will be held onto other things for as long as its active and only become GC-ed when it's no longer active. *You* are creatinga weak reference to the location result. The location result is a small, usually short-lived object that exists only to transfer some values. So it'll not be referenced by anyone other than you. So if you only reference it via a weak reference, it will be GCed almost immediately.

Comment: As Joachim says ... except "will be GCed almost immediately" should strictly say "**could** be ...".